# Como guardar varios registros en un mismo campo en PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Saludos (Tratare de explicarme)

Tengo una **tabla** en mi base de datos en **phpmyadmin** con varios campos (Me encuentro trabajando todo normal hasta que me topo con el siguiente problema pero antes te muestro la tabla):

**ID | Nombre | Diseño | Icono | Versión | Comentarios**

Bueno resulta que tengo un campo llamado **"Comentarios"**. Ese **CAMPO** pretendo usarlo para que los usuarios que lleguen a la web **escriban y envíen desde un formulario**  un **comentario de 100 caracteres**

La pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo hago para que un campo de PHP MY ADMIN me guarde varios registros (Ósea varios "Comentarios" en el mismo campo)

¿Es eso que pregunto posible? o a caso ¿Tendré que crear una tabla nueva y exclusiva para guardar comentarios?

//////////Me explico mas aquí ABAJO ///////

Necesito guardar cada uno de los **comentarios**: Es decir el campo COMENTARIO es un VARCHAR de 100 caracteres...

PERO yo **necesito guardar cada comentario como un "OBJETO"** (Por llamarlo así) ¿Me explico?

Es decir cada comentario debe representar una "ENTIDAD" para luego yo pasarle un COUNT* desde PHP y llevar un registro de cuantos comentarios hay en total y también poder PUBLICARLOS en la misma web

Comment: PhpMyadmin es un cliente que te ayuda a administrar una base de datos mysql/mariaDB. Tu pregunta es acerca del campo "Comentarios" de mysql entiendo, indistintamente de que gestor usas.
Lo que querés hacer es que cualquier usuario escriba en el mismo campo de un ID determinado?...si es asi cual sería la finalidad de esa lógica?

Comment: Pues guardar los comentarios: Es decir un COMENTARIO es un VARCHAR de 100 caracteres...

Yo necesito guardar cada comentario como un "OBJETO" (Por llamarlo así) ¿Me explico? 

Es decir cada comentario debe representar una "ENTIDAD" para luego yo pasarle un COUNT* desde PHP y llevar un registro de cuantaos comentarios hay en total y también poder PUBLICARLOS en la misma web

Comment: Mejor te creas una tabla aparte con tres columnas, una con un ID autoincremental, otra columna de **comentarios** y otra columna que contenga el ID de la otra tabla, pues lo que pides es una relación 1->n (uno a muchos, es decir, que cada ID de esa otra tabla puede tener muchos comentarios... si te he entendido bien).  Y modificas las consultas para que use ambas tablas con un JOIN de ese campo común cuando necesites acceder a los comentarios.

Comment: Como bien dice masterguru, lo lógico en este caso es trabajar con 2 tablas:
Ej:
tabla 1 - ID | Nombre | Diseño | Icono | Versión
tabla 2 - id_comentario (autoincrement) | IDt1 | comentario

Donde el IDt1 (tabla 2 ) este relacionada al ID de la tabla 1.

Comment: En efecto; Tuve una gran sospecha de que esto ya era una relación de 1-a MUCHOS. Solo que es algo a lo que no me había enfrentado y tuve que ponerme a pensar...

Lo curioso es que tengo como 8 tablas así, lo que me daría un resultado de 16 tablas por eso fue que me pareció tan raro que pudiera ser de esta manera y aunque aun no lo deduzco al 100% todo parece indicar que es así:

Posible solución como dijo masterguru; Es una relación de 1 a muchos (Para el que pase por algo parecido).

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, dices que tienes 8 tablas con comentarios, y claro, si las separas una a una te saldrán un total de 16.  Pues yo me plantearia que fueran 9 solo, es decir, creas una nueva tabla de comentarios con **4** columnas, donde habría las 3 que ya hemos dicho y una cuarta columna que sea el nombre de la tabla a la cual pertenece el comentario. Ejemplo:  **id (autoincremental) | id_tabla (se corresponde con el id de la tabla a la cual pertenece el comentario) | comentario | tabla (aquí iría el nombre de tabla)**, y de nuevo a modificar las consultas para que cuadre todo bien :-)

Comment: Luego, para que las consultas sean más ágiles, puedes crear un índice en la nueva tabla que contenga solo la columna **tabla**, y eso acelerará las consultas que le hagas para cada tabla.

Comment: masterguru hay algo que no comprendo; A que te refieres con -- "ID de la otra tabla" -- Es decir ¿De donde saco ese "ID"  Las tablas tienen un ID?

Comment: El ID suele ser una columna de las tablas,normalmente es la clave primaria y autoincremental que permite apuntar a los registros de las tablas de forma única para la acutalización y supresión de registros. Si tus tablas no tienen ID ni clave primaria entonces tienes un lio monumental en ellas, pues solo puedes acceder a su registros por valores con clausulas WHERE en sus consultas. Si te fijas en tu propia pregunta, la primera columna de tu tabla es un ID, que imagino primaria y autoincremental. Ese es el ID al que me refiero, que debes usar en la tabla de comentarios para enlazarlas.

Comment: Cuando digo lo de clausulas WHERE me refiero, por ejemplo, a que en lugar de hacer un update así:  `UPDATE tabla SET Nombre="un nombre" WHERE ID="5"`, tendrías que hacerlo así (si no hubiera ID): `UPDATE tabla SET Nombre="un nombre" WHERE Nombre="nombre anterior"` con el peligro que eso comporta, porque quizás tienes varios registros con el valor "nombre anterior" en es tabla y ese UPDATE te los actualizaria todos a la vez en lugar de solo uno.

Comment: maseterguru te menciono que parece que eh logrado hacer la llave foranea (Y en efecto la solución era hace una TABLA APARTE que se llame COMENTARIOS y en efecto las vinculo con el ID de la TABLA que ilustre en primer lugar...) 

Pero hasta ahora estoy haciendo 1 TABLA COMENTARIOS para cada ; 

TABLA ID | Nombre | Diseño | Icono | Versión | 

Y yo te preguntaba porque sugerías un "4to campo más" tu dijiste que para no hacer 1 tabla comentario por cada TABLA de "DISEÑO" que tengo pero al final solo use 3 campos:  ID|ID-TablaForanea|Comentarios (No entedí a que te referias con el 4to campo

Comment: Quizás fui yo quien no te entendió a ti cuando me parecia que decias que tenias 8 tablas con campos de comentarios a las cuales ibas ha hacer lo mismo. Da igual, tampoco podemos extender demasiado más esta conversación en los comentarios pues esto no es un foro y nos van a reñir con razón. Si ya lo tienes solucionado me parece perfecto :-)  Saludos!

Comment: ¿Tendré que crear una tabla nueva y exclusiva para guardar comentarios?. La respuesta es si amigo

Comment: JGuerreroS pero la pregunta es como vinculo el campo "COMENTARIO" con esa tabla (Pregunto):

¿Se hace a travez de una relación de 1 a muchos? o con un TRIGGER